# How to throw an error if user role is not allowed Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am trying to leverage the Laravel auth system and add logic that does not allow you to log in if you have the user role of `user`. I want to extend authenticate users.

```php
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->guard()->user();

    $request->session()->regenerate();
    if ($user->role != 'admin') {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'You do not have permissions to view this page');

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
            ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
}
```

The issue is it still logs me in. How can I make this logic work?

Comment: This is called *after* you are logged in. You need to override before that happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this function to your LoginController, it will override the default function and add an extra constraint for logging in:

```
/**
 * override to add check
 * 
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    $credentials['role'] = 'admin'; //only login admin

    return $credentials;
}
```